# How to reproject a multiline string shapefile without losing distance information?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

i would like to reproject a map (multi-linestring shapefile) from "EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected" to "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic" and create buffer area around the new reprojected file. However, I found that after using "Reproject layer" function, I am losing my distance detail which means I cannot set buffer distance in specific length unit. I attached the images before and after I reproject.

This is the original file under CRS:"EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected"
[image]

This is the image after I reprojected the map into CRS:"EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic" (As you can see, the distance for buffer became an exclamation point)
[image]

I would like to keep the distance information of the shapefile after reprojection.

The QGIS version I used is 3.16.14

Comment: Buffer before reprojecting, then reproject both layers.  Noting that EPSG:3857 is not very useful for distances anyway. It's designed for web mapping not analysis.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.